# facebook feed image large size with GraphAPI in Objective C

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a facebook feed picture and get below url from graph api

http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCM2k7sUFsWqmAh&w=154&h=154&url=http%3A%2F%2Frack.3.mshcdn.com%2Fmedia%2FZgkyMDE0LzAzLzA1Lzg0L2xvcmRlY292ZXIuMjE5NjguanBnCnAJdGh1bWIJMTIwMHg2MjcjCmUJanBn%2F89249d58%2F77d%2Florde-cover.jpg

How can I get a large image rather than thumbnail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide the code you used to get this image URL. This does not look like a graph API url to me.

Comment: This is the image url i get from the responses to get facebook feeds.

Comment: adding an answer with more info.

Comment: I got the solution how can i get big image,
Docde the url and take the substring start from &url= to end of the string and give me url looks like http://rack.3.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE0LzAzLzA1Lzg0L2xvcmRlY292ZXIuMjE5NjguanBnCnAJdGh1bWIJMTIwMHg2MjcjCmUJanBn/89249d58/77d/lorde-cover.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is Facebook's filtered URL, which they use to display a cached thumbnail of an externally linked/hosted image. You can see the full/original image by grabbing the entire url after `url=`. Here is what it actually is, decoded

`http://rack.3.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDE0LzAzLzA1Lzg0L2xvcmRlY292ZXIuMjE5NjguanBnCnAJdGh1bWIJMTIwMHg2MjcjCmUJanBn/89249d58/77d/lorde-cover.jpg`

If you are getting these from the feed, they are probably coming from image links in comments, and it doesn't appear that Facebook caches a bigger version of these, so this is probably what you'll have to do to get the full image.

The cached Facebook URL actually has width and height parameters (`w=154&h=154`) but there doesn't appear to be a cached image for any other values of these, so I am assuming that one size is probably all they saved.

edit: and welcome to stackoverflow!